# how to use AFNetworking to connect website

Tags: iphone, xcode, afnetworking

I'm sorry but I am a beginner.
How to use AFNetworking to connect website:

```
I have login: xxx
password: yyy
```

and i have to do query:

```
{
              "method": "authorize",
              "params": [
                "100000202",
                "TestApp677"`
              ]
            }
```

to endpoint:  http://qqqqq.com/authorize/?ver=2_01

I read start guide and i added the library,but i do not know how to begin.

i have:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://qqqqq.com/mobileapi/authorize/?ver=2_01"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
    [client registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
    [client setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:@"xxx" password:@"yyy"];
```

what next?

**update**

---

When i used code from Jano, I get this error:

```
<code>
Error Domain=com.alamofire.networking.error Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
    "text/json",
    "application/json",
    "text/javascript"
)}, got text/html" UserInfo=0x6875ce0<br> {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://qqqqq.com/authorize/?ver=2_01,
NSLocalizedDescription=Expected content type {(
    "text/json",
    "application/json",
    "text/javascript"
)}, got text/html}
```

**UPDATE**

---

I change 2 line

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL
```

URLWithString:@"http://qqqqq.com/mobileapi"]];

and

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/authorize/?ver=2_01" 
parameters:jsonDic];
```

and i get error:

```
Error Domain=com.alamofire.networking.error Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299), got
 404" UserInfo=0x68562b0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://qqqqq.com/authorize/?ver=2_01, 
NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 404}
```

**UPDATE**

---

My code looks like:

```
 <code>NSMutableDictionary *jsonDic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [jsonDic setObject:@"authorize" forKey:@"method"];
        [jsonDic setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"100000202",@"TestApp677", nil] forKey:@"params"];

        AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxxxx.com"]];
        [client registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
        [client setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:@"mobileapi" password:@"M031leA#p1"];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/mobileapi/authorize/?ver=2_01" parameters:jsonDic];

    [client setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];

    [AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"]];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation
                                         JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                         success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON){
                                             NSLog(@"%@",JSON);
                                         }
                                         failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
                                             NSLog(@"%@",error);
                                         }];
    [client enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];</code>

and i get error:

Error Domain=JKErrorDomain Code=-1 "Unexpected token, wanted '{', '}', '[', ']', ',', ':', 'true', 'false', 'null', '"STRING"', 'NUMBER'." UserInfo=0x6d47460 {JKAtIndexKey=0, JKLineNumberKey=1, NSLocalizedDescription=Unexpected token, wanted '{', '}', '[', ']', ',', ':', 'true', 'false', 'null', '"STRING"', 'NUMBER'.}

<B>UPDATE</B>

----------

MY CODE IS A LOOK LIKE:

    NSString* encodeToPercentEscapeString(NSString *string) {
        return (NSString *)
        CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                                  (__bridge CFStringRef) string,
                                                                  NULL,
                                                                  (CFStringRef) @"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                                                  kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        //NSMutableDictionary *jsonDic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        //[jsonDic setObject:@"authorize" forKey:@"method"];
        //

[jsonDic setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"100000202",@"TestApp677", nil] forKey:@"params"];


        NSDictionary *jsonDic = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"method\":\"authorize\",\"params\":\[\"100000202\",\"TestApp\"]}",nil];


        NSLog(@"%@", jsonDic);

        NSString *password = encodeToPercentEscapeString(@"M031leA#p1");

        AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://vemmaeurope.com"]];
        [client registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
        [client setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:@"mobileapi" password:password];


        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/mobileapi/authorize/?ver=2_01" parameters:jsonDic];

        [client setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
        [AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"]];

        AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation
                                             JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                             success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON){
                                                 NSLog(@"%@",JSON);
                                             }
                                             failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
                                                 NSLog(@"%@",error);
                                             }];
        [client enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
```

and and I still have the same error:

```
Error Domain=JKErrorDomain Code=-1 "Unexpected token, wanted '{', '}', '[', ']', ',', ':', 
'true', 'false', 'null', '"STRING"', 'NUMBER'." UserInfo=0x6c40cd0 {JKAtIndexKey=0, 
JKLineNumberKey=1, NSLocalizedDescription=Unexpected token, wanted '{', '}', '[', ']', ',', ':', 
'true', 'false', 'null', '"STRING"', 'NUMBER'.}
```

Comment: How far have you gotten?  Have you read the getting started guide?  Have you added the library to your application?  Have you made a request?  Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: Yes, read start guide and i added the library,but i do not know how to begin.

Comment: The start guide explains how to begin.  How far into the start guide did you get?  Which bit did you get stuck on?

Comment: I don't know how to add query.

Comment: The start guide tells you to use `AFHTTPClient`.  Have you done so?

Comment: Yes, i used AFHTTPClient

Answer (score 0):

The following enchantment may be of help:

```
NSMutableDictionary *jsonDic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[jsonDic setObject:@"authorize" forKey:@"method"];
[jsonDic setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"100000202",@"TestApp677", nil] forKey:@"params"];

AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://qqqqq.com"]];
[client registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
[client setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:@"xxx" password:@"yyy"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"/authorize/?ver=2_01" parameters:jsonDic];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation
                                     JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                     success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON){
                                         NSLog(@"%@",JSON);
                                     }
                                     failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
                                         NSLog(@"%@",error);
                                     }];
[client enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

Replace GET with POST if it doesn't work.

**update**

If you have unusual characters on your paramters, eg: @"M031leA#p1" replace the parameter @"M031leA#p1" with encodeToPercentEscapeString(@"M031leA#p1") and then paste the following C function anywhere inside your class:

```
// remove CFBridgingRelease and __bridge if your code is not ARC
NSString* encodeToPercentEscapeString(NSString *string) {
    return (NSString *)
        CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                            (__bridge CFStringRef) string,
                                            NULL,
                                            (CFStringRef) @"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                            kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
}
```

Comment: the problem is the server returns the wrong content type, you should fix that on the server if you can

Comment: if you can't fix it on the server try this: `[AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObjects:@"text/html",nil]`

Comment: i get this error: Error Domain=JKErrorDomain Code=-1 "Unexpected token, wanted '{', '}', '[', ']', ',', ':', 'true', 'false', 'null', '"STRING"', 'NUMBER'." UserInfo=0x6d47460 {JKAtIndexKey=0, JKLineNumberKey=1, NSLocalizedDescription=Unexpected token, wanted '{', '}', '[', ']', ',', ':', 'true', 'false', 'null', '"STRING"', 'NUMBER'.}